# what's the use case of webpack-dev-server's option devServer.index

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

i just don't know what's the use case of option [devServer.index](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server#devserverindex).

I thought changes to this option will be reflected in devServer.historyApiFallback option, but after i start the dev-server (set devServer.index to 'demo.html'), console tells me that '404s will fallback to /index.html', not '/demo.html'.

After several minutes of googling, i failed finding any example of this option.

Can anyone explain and give an example for better understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusion:**
devServer.index configuration has no relation to directory access rules except for the directory specified by [devServer.publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server#devserverpublicpath-).

**explanation:**
how dev-server response to requests to directories are determined by server itself, and i guess every time you access directories from static served resources, the dev-server will response you with an index file(such as index.html) under that folder. *But, change to option devServer.index will not affect this rule. It only affects the directory specified by option devServer.publicPath.* By default, dev-server will not find index file for requests to directories under publicPath and will give a 404 response. After you change devServer.index to value 'index.html', server will response those requests with file 'index.html' under their requested folder. That's the use case of this option.

**tips:**

- provided option value will all be treated as relative path (server-relative is not available), relative to devServer.publicPath.
- you can specify any type of file, not just html.

**Please correct my answer if there's any mistake, thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Call me a fuddy duddy stuck in the mud but I grew up calling my HTML files index.htm, so having to create an index.html now, just for webpack, broke my heart. So, after a few well spent hours trying to fix it, I finally came across this post, just afterwards, and this bug report:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2540

The upshot of all that is, if you wanna change the name of the file served up as the index in your public directory using webpack dev server, do something this:

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true,
    staticOptions: { index: 'index.htm' }
  },
```

Note the `staticOptions: { index: 'index.htm' }`. That's where the magic happens.

Which is to say, I agree, the devServer.index property seemingly does nothing. But the thing it definitely should do, is possible. Phew.